# Is my Inception V3 model overfitted or is it fine to have those fluctuations?

Tags: python, pre-trained-model, overfitting-underfitting

In this post, I have added graphs of both accuracy and loss of basic inception v3 model and another inception v3 model with dropout layer. Can anyone tell me whether these models are overfitted or not by looking at the graphs.

### Basic Inception V3 model graphs

[image: Accuracy]

[image: loss]

### Inception V3 with Dropout layer

[image: balanced_accuracy]

[image: balanced_loss]

Answer (score 1):

Learning rate is too high, the `val_loss` should be more smooth. So far overfitting does not seem to happen,

Comment: At initial training, i used 'adam' optimizer with default learning rate. Now i'm fine-tuning the models(with same dataset) by unfreezing first two layers and with 'SGD' optimizer with learning rate of 0.0001 and momentum of 0.9. will it work?

Comment: Having a lower learning rate will help yes